# How to explain this profilng data of Haskell random generator for huge memory usage and low speed?

Tags: haskell, optimization, random, ghc

I want to profile the speed of Haskell random generator, and my test case is to generate 1000000 double precision random numbers range from zero to one and calculate their sum. here is my code:

```
import System.Random
import System.Environment
import Control.Monad.State
import Data.Time.Clock
type Seed = Int
intDayTime :: IO Int
intDayTime = getCurrentTime >>= return.(floor.utctDayTime :: UTCTime->Int)
n = 1000000 :: Int
main :: IO ()
main = do
    calc <- getArgs >>= return . (read ::(String->Int)).head
    seed <- intDayTime 
    let calcit :: Int->Double 
        calcit 1 = calc1 n seed 
        calcit 2 = calc2 n (mkStdGen seed)
        calcit _ = error "error calculating" 
     in print $ calcit calc
calc1 ::Int->Seed->Double
calc1 n initSeed = 
  let next      :: Seed->(Double,Seed) -- my simple random number generator, just for test
      myRandGen :: State Seed Double 
      calc      :: Int->Int->Seed->Double->Double 
      next seed = let x = (1103515245 * seed + 12345) `mod` 1073741824 in (((fromIntegral x)/1073741824),x)
      myRandGen = state next 
      calc _ 0 _ r = r
      calc n c s r = calc n (c-1) ns (r + nv)
        where (nv,ns) = runState myRandGen s 
     in calc n n initSeed 0
calc2 ::Int->StdGen->Double
calc2 n initSeed = 
    let myRandGen :: State StdGen Double 
        calc      :: Int->Int->StdGen->Double->Double 
        next      :: StdGen->(Double,StdGen)
        next gen  = randomR (0,1) gen
        myRandGen = state next
        calc _ 0 _ r = r
        calc n c s r = calc n (c-1) ns (r + nv)
          where (nv,ns) = runState myRandGen s 
       in calc n n initSeed 0
```

and I compile the code with

```
ghc profRandGen.hs -O3 -prof -fprof-auto -rtsopts
```

run with

```
./profRandGen.exe 1 +RTS -o # for calc1
./profRandGen.exe 2 +RTS -o # for calc2
```

and the profiling data for calc1 is

```
total time  =        0.10 secs   (105 ticks @ 1000 us, 1 processor)
total alloc = 128,121,344 bytes  (excludes profiling overheads)
```

profiling data for calc1 is

```
total time  =        1.48 secs   (1479 ticks @ 1000 us, 1 processor)
total alloc = 2,008,077,560 bytes  (excludes profiling overheads)
```

I can understand that the random generator in `System.Random`would be slower, but why would it be slower so much and why would it allocating much more memory?

I used **tail recursion** in my code and compiled with `-O2 -fforce-recomp` option, why didn't I get constant memory usage?

is there anything wrong in my code? for example, is it because there being lazy evaluation that tail recursion is not optimized and a lot of memory is allocated? If so,How could this program be further optimized?

Comment: Constant memory usage? With Haskell? I never heard about that since pretty much anything in Haskell allocs. I guess that is part of the point, actually... also, I think there is no -O3, only -O2. Also, make sure to have `-fforce-recomp`.

Comment: Well... I heard that if I compile with `-O2`, tail call would be optimized, so I guess that I might get constant memory usage...

Comment: You can safely count on the tail call optimization and the function will not grow a stack. That way, if you, for example, write a function that does nothing but add numbers together, then I guess that function will get constant memory usage. But as soon as you do anything inside it that needs allocation (which is pretty much anything in Haskell), you have to pay for it. That is my guess, though - I find it very unlikely that you can get an actual constant memory Haskell program, but I might be wrong.

Comment: Make your accumulator strict.

Comment: @Viclib In my experience it's almost very common to optimize loops so that they'll run in constant space if you're being lazy. See the `means` example in Real World Haskell over [here](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/profiling-and-optimization.html). The tail-recursive and strictly accumulated version runs in constant space.

Comment: @Viclib Constant space doesn't mean "no allocation". It just means that memory is freed as quickly as it is allocated.

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel Wagner says in the comments, your state accumulator is not strict. First off, try to import `Control.Monad.State.Strict`. That may itself be enough! Otherwise, you also need to alter `myRandGen` such that it more thoroughly forces the new generator before replacing it in the state.